# nchar() throwing unused argument (keepNA = TRUE)

Tags: r

```
x <- c("asfef", "qwerty", "NA", "b", "stuff.blah.yech")
nchar(x, keepNA= TRUE)
```

The above command is throwing me an error:

> unused argument (keepNA = TRUE)

Can anybody help me in telling why is it throwing an error and what can be done to overcome it?

Comment: I cannot replicate the error.

Comment: What R version you are using? I cannot reproduce this behaviour. BTW, if you want to test for `NA` values, you should type it without quotes: `x <- c("asfef", "qwerty", NA, "b", "stuff.blah.yech")`

Comment: [This doesn't happen on R version 3.3.2](http://rextester.com/AGQ42571).  But you don't have any `NA` values, so the warning (not an error) makes sense.

Comment: I am using R version 3.0.3.I typed NA without quotes as told by you. Still, i am getting the same error. I should be getting the output as : nchar(x, keepNA= TRUE) #  5  6 NA  1 15
nchar(x, keepNA=FALSE) #  5  6  2  1 15

Comment: It throws me an error stating "Error in nchar(x, type = "width", keepNA = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (keepNA = TRUE)"

Comment: It's clear - update your R version. `keepNA` was added aroud 3.2: https://bitbucket.org/kleinstein/alakazam/issues/36/wont-build-on-r-320

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is now working.